# C++ know if a member function is called

Tags: c++, struct

How can I know if a method is called, but very early?

For example, I have a struct Foo that has some configurable members:

```cpp
struct Foo {
  int a;
  int b;

  Foo& setA(int a) {
    this->a = a;
    return *this;
  }

  Foo& setB(int b) {
    this->b = b;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Now I have a function that returns a Foo AND should use it immediately if there are no further calls to member functions.

For example:

```cpp
Foo getFoo() {
    static Foo foo;
    // <-- Here, I want to call some useFoo(foo) if no member functions are called
    return foo;
}

// This function is used like this:
getFoo().setA(3);
        ^-- here, we call setA so don't useFoo now

getFoo();
        ^-- but here, I want useFoo to be called automatically
```

Comment: Why not have two variations of `getFoo()`? One returning `void`, and one returning `Foo`, marked as `[[nodiscard]]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Would two such functions would need different parameters? Or is [[nodiscard]] enough to distinguish them?

Comment: @john I meant with two different names. Should've explicitly said that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're proposing in your question is physically not possible; it would break causality:  You cannot call `useFoo` if no member functions have been called **before** returning it and possibly using it, because after you return it you could use some member function.

What you *can* do is call `useFoo` from the destructor of `Foo` if a flag has not been set, and set that flag on each member function call.  You need to take care of how to handle copies / moves then, though!